# MouseLeftButtonDown event on TextBlock in TabControl header not firing

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a TabControl defined like this:

```
<TabControl x:Class="MyNamespace.TabContainer"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"            
     ItemsSource="{Binding}">

<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="MaxLines" Value="5000"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mouseOverColor" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="glowColor" Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.5"></GradientStop>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="glowMask" Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
        <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"></GradientStop>
        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
    </RadialGradientBrush>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
        <DockPanel>
            <Button Name="btn_TabDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btn_TabDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                <Image Source="icon_grey_cross.gif" Height="9" Width="9" Margin="0,0,0,0"></Image>
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="bdr_main" Margin="4" BorderThickness="0" >
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,4,4,4" ContentSource="Content" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource glowColor}"></Setter>
                                <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="OpacityMask" Value="{StaticResource glowMask}"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock MouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

It works fine except for one thing; the OnMouseLeftButtonDown event never fires when I click on the TextBlock.

To be clear, when I say it 'never fires' I base that on the fact that I am placing a breakpoint on the first line of UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown() and the breakpoint is not hit when I click the text in the tab header. Using PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown works no better.

What am I going wrong here? It looks like it should be pretty straightforward and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Events inside `DataTemplates` won't hook up your event to the correct handler. You need to manually attach the event for each textblock once it is created.

**Update**

You have to access the `Template` property of each `TabItem` and then call `FindName` give your `TextBlock` a name so it can find it.

Given `tabItem` is `TabItem` do

`tabItem.Template.FindName(tabItem, "textBlockName") as TextBlock`

Comment: How do I access that TextBlock inside the DataTemplate after I create an instance of TabContainer?

Comment: FindName() seems to want two parameters; the name (as you provided) and the templatedParent described as 'The context of the FrameworkElement where this template is applied'. How do I obtain the context?

Comment: @davecove Sorry, pass the `tabItem`

Comment: Still something amiss: my code is TabItem tabAdd = new TabItem();
            tabAdd.Header = "+";
            tabAdd.FontSize = 18;
            TextBlock tb = tabAdd.Template.FindName("textBlock", tabAdd) as TextBlock;

Comment: Still something amiss... my code is:
    TabItem tabAdd = new TabItem();
    _tabItems.Add(tabAdd);  // a List<TabItem>
    TextBlock tb = tabAdd.Template.FindName("textBlock", tabAdd) as TextBlock;

and tb comes back null.

Comment: You are instantiating new tab item without saying that the data template is what you defined in your xaml.